# with spring cloud stream binding to pulsar the dead letter policy doesn't apply to the consumer

Tags: spring-cloud, spring-cloud-stream, spring-pulsar

I am using spring cloud stream bindings to consume pulsar messages with. `implementation("org.springframework.pulsar:spring-pulsar-spring-cloud-stream-binder:0.1.1-SNAPSHOT")` this library is used.
Following is the application.yaml configuration.

```
# pulsar
  pulsar:
    client:
      service-url: pulsar://localhost:6650
  cloud:
    function:
      definition: notificationListener
    stream:
      bindings:
        notificationListener-in-0:
          destination: notification
          consumer:
            use-native-decoding: true

      pulsar:
        bindings:
          notificationListener-in-0:
            consumer:
              negative-ack-redelivery-delay: 1s
              dead-letter-policy:
                dead-letter-topic: notification-dlq
                max-redeliver-count: 5
              schema-type: JSON
              message-type: global.din.notification.data.dto.BrokerMessage
```

but the given **dead-letter-policy** doesn't apply to the **topic** and **consumer**.

Comment: The dead-letter feature for the binder is still WIP. We will let you know here once this is ready for you to try.

Comment: Hi @noor-khan - we created a Github issue for this work. Feel free to add yourself to it for notifications etc.. https://github.com/spring-projects-experimental/spring-pulsar/issues/373

Comment: @onobc I have changed **subscription-type** to **Shared** , now it is applying dead letter policy. but then it redeliver the message even if it is successfully consumed. and it seems issue in the given dependency.